# Javascript/HTML Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Web Development with Javascript and HTML.
My problem is that I'm trying to implement a for loop (2nd method) that do some logic instead of the redudant code (1st method) but I can't seem to get method 2 working. Please see if there is any other mistake in method 2, I rlly don't like the fact typing the id for each button over and over again. Let me know how I can fix or improve method 2, thanks a lot!

**UPDATED**

```
<div id="num">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="1">
                    <input type="button" value="2">
                    <input type="button" value="3">
                    <input type="button" value="+">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="4">
                    <input type="button" value="5">
                    <input type="button" value="6">
                    <input type="button" value="-">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="7">
                    <input type="button" value="8">
                    <input type="button" value="9">
                    <input type="button" value="*">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="/">
                    <input type="button" value="0">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <br>
            <input type="button" value="=" onClick="document.calculator.ans.value=eval(document.calculator.ans.value)">
            <br>Solution is <input type="textfield" name="ans" value="">
        </form>
```

```
    <script>

        const num = document.getElementById("num");
        const length = num.length;
        obj.onclick = function() 
        { 
            for (let i = 1; i < length; i++)
            {
                num.addEventListener("click")
            }
        }
    </script></strike>
```

Comment: You don't have an element with the id of `num`. It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'm trying to get the id of the buttons.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#num")` is attempting to find an element with the id of `num`. You don't have one.

Comment: I just wanna get all the buttons how I do that then?

Comment: Give the buttons you want to deal with all the same class. Then use `document.querySelectorAll(".theclass")`. But it's still not clear what you're trying to with them all. Also `querySelectorAll` returns an array-like result, not one item...

Comment: The *value attribute* is not the same as *value property*. The attribute doesn't get updated by user input (keyboard, paste etc)

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of the numbers that are submitted by the buttons, Maybe I don't the logic inside of the loop wrong and that's why I need some help.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Did you understand what i'm trying to archieve now, Lee Taylor? I only want to sum the buttons I'm clicking on instead of making redudant code as seen in method 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create one event listener for every button. It is enough to use ONE on an element that somewhere contains the buttons.

This is an example of how I would start to do what you are trying to do.

```js
function handle(event) {
  // The clicked element is in event.target
  const button = event.target; 
  
  // using the name of the clicked element to determine what to do.
  if (button.name === "digit") {
    const value = Number(button.value);
    console.log("Digit %d was pressed", value);
  }
  else if (button.name === "op") {
    switch(button.value) {
      case "+":{
        console.log("Operator +");
        break;
      }
      case "-":{
        console.log("Operator -");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  
}

const pad = document.getElementById("pad");
pad.addEventListener("click", handle); // Attach ONE click-handler
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  <button name="digit" value="1">1</button>
  <button name="digit" value="2">2</button>
  <button name="digit" value="3">3</button>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <!--
            The don't have to be direct chilren.
            As long as they are somewhere inside the
            div that have the event-handler the event
            handler will see them.
          -->
          <button name="op" value="+">+</button>
          <button name="op" value="-">-</button>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You requested in a comment a way to use for-loops instead. Here is an example: I'm using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Feedback) to get all the elements and then [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over the array-like result.

The key here is to give all the buttons that have the same meaning something that can be selected. In my example I have set the name-attribute/property on all buttons, "digit" for digits, and "op" for operators, and then use the value-attribute/property to know what the button is supposed to do.

```js
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll("button[name=digit]")){
  console.log("Digit", elem.value);
}

for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll("button[name=op]")){
  console.log("Operator", elem.value);
}

// With a low-level for-loop
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("button[name=digit]");
const length = elements.length;
for (let index=0; index < length; index += 1) {
  const elem = elements[index];
  console.log("Long way to get the value of digit",elem.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  <button name="digit" value="1">1</button>
  <button name="digit" value="2">2</button>
  <button name="digit" value="3">3</button>
  <button name="op" value="+">+</button>
  <button name="op" value="-">-</button>
</div>
```

**Let us go though your code**

```
    obj = document.querySelectorAll("#num");
    // You start by asking for all elements with an id of "num".
    // querySelectorAll returns a static node list with matching
    // elements. An id should be unique in a document. So there should only
    // be ONE matching element. 




    obj.onclick = function() 
    // here you try to add a click handler to obj. But obj is not an
    // element. It is a list of nodes. 


    { 
        // this for-loop looks alright....
        for (let i = 1; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            // But here you are trying to add eventlisteners inside a
            // an eventlistener. You don't want to add that on every
            // click. 
            obj[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Here you are using getAttribute, but you don't need that.
                console.log(obj[i].getAttribute('value'))
                // You can access value as a property:
                // console.log(obj[i].value)
            })
        }
    }
```

Looking at your other atempt:

```
const num = document.getElementById("num");
// Now you are using getElementById, that will give you the
// node of your outer div. That is a good start, but you
// don't get the individual buttons.


const length = num.length;
obj.onclick = function() 
{ 
    // you are starting with 1, but javascript is it 0 based.
    for (let i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        num.addEventListener("click")
    }
}
```

What you could do (untested, might contain errors):

```
// Get a static node list of all buttons.
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
const length = buttons.length;

// event handler that will be called when a button i clicked.
function handle(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  switch ( value ) {
     case "+" :
      console.log("+ was clicked");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("%s was clicked", value);
  }
}

// Adding the event handler to the buttons.
for( let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", handle);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Please can you give an example with a for loop. I really want to stick to that method.

Comment: @Zagros I added some more examples that should get you started.

Comment: I'm sorry, it don't look like the method I wanted (look at method 2 screenshot). I'm new to Javascript and HTML. Cannot seem to get your method implemented in mine.

Comment: @Zagros I have updated my answer with even more examples. I have tried to show you a good way to solve what I'm guessing you are trying to do. I have also added examples with for-loop, and with adding event handlers to each and every button. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it man! I think I'm almost there, can you explain me where the "elem" is coming from in "buttons[i].elem.addEventlistener"? Also it seems like "const value = event.target.value" don't work.

Comment: @Zagros Sorry, my mistake. It should be `buttons[i].addEventListener("click", handle);}`. As I said, the last piece of code was untested. I updated it. I hope that you learn something new. :)

Comment: Appreciate your time, sorry for the inconvenience. As I said I'm trying to learn this, tougher than I thought. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the buttons (`#num1`, `#num2`, `#num3`... etc.) then you need to use the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="num"]');
```

The CSS selector

```
[id^="num"]
```

means:

*every element that has an `id` attribute, where the `id` **begins with** "num".*

---

**N.B.** Note that the method `.querySelectorAll()` returns a **NodeList** object which is *array-like* but ***not*** an array.

If you want an array, you can use the spread operator (`...`):

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('[id^="num"]')];
```

Comment: Looks like the solution to me, I will try it tomorrow and then see what's up. Thanks a lot. About the .querySelectorAll(), if there is a better way to do it with the for loop. Let me know please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const myButtons = [... document.querySelectorAll('[id^="num"]')];` is much more concise than a `for` loop.

Comment: I have updated my initial post please look at it and see what I need to do.

Comment: I suspect what you are actually looking for is **Event Delegation**. This will enable you to apply a single event listener to the parent div. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target